# Do I have to use 'these' or 'the'?

Tags: word-choice

'This video is aimed at individuals who use violence against social workers, because they are called upon to keep their hands off these/the persons that are always ready to help us.'

Do I have to use 'these' or 'the' in this sentence?

Comment: I'm not a native speaker of English, but I find the fluctuation in style throughout the entire sentence quite noticeable (and the sentence therefore comes off as artificially constructed, "stitched"). I don't understand the *because*. That comma should ideally be a period, and everything that comes after it scrapped (most preferably) or rewritten (*call (up)on* is a good idiom to keep handy here, however). Normally a video (being a collection of pictures, each a thousand words) should speak for itself, so do consider binning everything after the *because*.

Comment: I’m not a native speaker neither but I agree with @userr2684291

Comment: What do you both think about the following sentence?        
'This video must be aimed at individuals who use violence against social workers, because they are called upon to keep their hands off the people that are always ready to help us.'

Comment: @Rowan Nah. It's an ugly sentence. The *because* doesn't make sense, and it's still an artificial string of English words which I don't want to have anything to do with. If I were you, I'd hire a native speaker to write these "announcements" or descriptions for your company.